# Changing the contents of a text field on change of a dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, function, drop-down-menu, onchange, select-menu

I am trying to use the following to change the value of 5 text boxes each time one of the 5 dropdown menus is changed. For some reason its not working though. I just want to take the value from the dropdown and put it into the text box, I dont need any other info such as the data between 
and  , just the value, im not sure why its not working though :-S . The value from the dropdown will be a number string, such as 458766958

```
    <script>
    $('#stock1').change(function() {
        $('#stock1T').val($('#stock1 option:selected').data('value'));
    })

    $('#stock2').change(function() {
        $('#stock2T').val($('#stock2 option:selected').data('value'));
    })

    $('#stock3').change(function() {
        $('#stock3T').val($('#stock3 option:selected').data('value'));
    })

    $('#stock4').change(function() {
        $('#stock4T').val($('#stock4 option:selected').data('value'));
    })

    $('#stock5').change(function() {
        $('#stock5T').val($('#stock5 option:selected').data('value'));
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Do your `option` elements have a `data-value` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `data()` ,try getting the selected value using `val()`

```
      $('#stock1').change(function() {
              $('#stock1T').val($('#stock1 option:selected').val());
         });
```